# Splitting two index entries whose ranges share a common page or are one page apart

Tags: makeindex

I am using makeindex to generate the index for a large textbook. I frequently have cases where two index entries using the same word or phrase share a common end page for the first range and beginning page for the second range. Makeindex does not show this as two distinct ranges but rather concatenates them into a single range. Even worse, if the beginning page of the second range is one page after the end of the first range, makeindex concatenates everything. Here is an example of what I want to see:

Pulse propagation, 319-323, 324-330

What I get is:

Pulse propagation, 319-330

This is especially troublesome when the two ranges cross a chapter boundary. Any suggestions on how to force the desired split?